# How do you iterate/parse through a CSV file to use in Ansible playbook?

Tags: ansible

I am new to Ansible and don't have much coding experience in general. I am trying to figure out how to provision RHEL servers using the [DellEMC OpenManage modules](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/dellemc/openmanage/index.html#plugins-in-dellemc-openmanage).

The first step to this is figuring out how to parse a CSV, that we are putting necessary information for the later templating. (IP, hostname, MAC, etc. ...) I can get it to print the data in general, but cant figure out how to parse/iterate through it.

CSV Sample

```
server_name,idrac_ip,idrac_user,idrac_pwd,idrac_nw,idrac_gw,idrac_mac,mgmt_ip,mgmt_nw,mgmt_gw,mgmt_mac,bond0_100_ip,bond0_200_ip,dns_1,bond0_100_nw,bond0_100_gw,bond0_100_vip,bond0_200_nw,bond0_200_gw,bond0_200_vip,os,fs,sio_type,mdm_name
test1,1.1.1.10,root,Password1234,1.1.1.0/24,1.1.1.1,00:00:00:00:00:01,1.1.1.142,1.1.62.0/24,1.1.2.1,98:03:9B:46:25:B3,1.1.1.22,1.1.1.21,1.1.1.26,1.1.61.15/24,1.1.61.1,1.1.61.29,1.1.66.0/24,1.1.66.1,1.1.1.29,RHEL 7.6,1,Master,MDM-1
```

Here is my playbook to print the info in general.

```yaml
---
- name: Parse
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local

  tasks:

    - name: Load CSV Data into object
      read_csv:
        path: 'Test_Lab_Servers.csv'
        fieldnames: server_name,idrac_ip,idrac_user,idrac_pwd,idrac_nw,idrac_gw,idrac_mac,mgmt_ip,mgmt_nw,mgmt_gw,mgmt_mac,bond0_100_ip,bond0_200_ip,dns_1,bond0_100_nw,bond0_100_gw,bond0_100_vip,bond0_200_nw,bond0_200_gw,bond0_200_vip,os,fs,sio_type,mdm_name
        delimiter: ','
      register: csv_output
      delegate_to: localhost

    - name: Print data
      debug:
        msg: "{{ csv_output }}"
```

Any advice?

Comment: You want to read the [`loops` page](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html) of the documentation.

Comment: Hi, yes I have been pouring over the documentation.  The problem is , and I apologize if my terminology is incorrect, it is outputting nested dictionaries or a list of dictionaries,  so am having trouble understanding how to parse/iterate over.

Comment: @Kenpachi429, regarding "_having trouble understanding how to parse/iterate over_" it is recommended to edit your question and describe what you have tried to do so and which problems you running into it. Otherwise we may left with pointing to existing documentation and providing the same but altered examples from there.

Comment: @Kenpachi429 so, your issue is iterating over the dictionary inside the list, then?

Comment: thank you all. The answer from @U880D clarified everything.

Answer (score 2):

According the [`read_csv`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/read_csv_module.html#parameters) module parameter documentation `fieldnames` are

> needed if the CSV does not have a header

only. Therefore you could remove it to get a list object which might be easier to parse.

```yaml
- name: Print data
  debug:
    msg: "{{ csv_output.list }}"
```

As already mentioned within the comments, to [iterate over the list elements](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#iterating-over-a-simple-list) you may use `loop`.

```yaml
  - name: Print data
    debug:
      msg: "{{ item }}"
    loop: "{{ csv_output.list }}"
```

With [extended loop variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#extended-loop-variables) you will have a better control about the [loop output](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#limiting-loop-output-with-label).

```yaml
  - name: Print data
    debug:
      msg: "{{ item }}"
    loop: "{{ csv_output.list }}"
    loop_control:
      extended: yes
      label: "{{ ansible_loop.index0 }}"
```

Resulting into an output of

```yaml
TASK [Print data] ***************
ok: [localhost] => (item=0) =>
  msg:
    bond0_100_gw: 1.1.61.1
    bond0_100_ip: 1.1.1.22
    bond0_100_nw: 1.1.61.15/24
    bond0_100_vip: 1.1.61.29
    bond0_200_gw: 1.1.66.1
    bond0_200_ip: 1.1.1.21
    bond0_200_nw: 1.1.66.0/24
    bond0_200_vip: 1.1.1.29
    dns_1: 1.1.1.26
    fs: '1'
    idrac_gw: 1.1.1.1
    idrac_ip: 1.1.1.10
    idrac_mac: 00:00:00:00:00:01
    idrac_nw: 1.1.1.0/24
    idrac_pwd: Password1234
    idrac_user: root
    mdm_name: MDM-1
    mgmt_gw: 1.1.2.1
    mgmt_ip: 1.1.1.142
    mgmt_mac: 98:03:9B:46:25:B3
    mgmt_nw: 1.1.62.0/24
    os: RHEL 7.6
    server_name: test1
    sio_type: Master
  ...
```

Specific items (fields) like `server_name` you could get simply by using

```yaml
      msg: "{{ item.server_name }}"
```

resulting into an output of

```yaml
TASK [Print data] ************
ok: [localhost] => (item=0) =>
  msg: test1
ok: [localhost] => (item=1) =>
  msg: test2
ok: [localhost] => (item=2) =>
  msg: test3
...
```